# VBA: Follow Link in existing Session - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

We have a Excel-List of URLs with a lot of parameters.
The problem is: The first time you follow a link, you get redirected to a ADFS-Login, which cuts some of the Parameters, since they have a maximum URL-length.

My question: Is there a possibility to tell excel (be it via VBA or default) to use an existing Session?

I tried some shennenigans, for example via Chrome: [Find the Window handle for a Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705797/find-the-window-handle-for-a-chrome-browser) or to take an existing IE-Window: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/553580-visual-basic-applications-macro-already-open-ie-window.html While I get an existing Window, it seems like it always gets redirected and the URL cut. Is there anyhow a possibility to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and post feedback

1. Open Sheet1
2. In Column A, from row 2 create your list of URLS
3. Insert ActiveXControl Microsoft Web Browser WebBrowser1
4. Size the control to your needs
5. Insert Control Button outside the bounds of the browser
6. Change name of the button to NextButton

Open Code Editor (Alt+F11)

In Sheet1 place the below code

```
Dim currentURLRow As Integer ''Sheet level variable

Sub NextButton_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim url As String

    ''VBA evaluates second expression even when the first of OR is true. So on error resume next helps here
    If currentURLRow = 0 Or Trim(Cells(currentURLRow, 1)) = "" Then
        ''First time or loop back
        currentURLRow = 2
    Else
        currentURLRow = currentURLRow + 1
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ''reset error so you know of any (good) errors

    url = Cells(currentURLRow, 1)

    ''Sheet1.WebBrowser1.Silent = True ''Uncomment this if you are seeing lot of script errors that you dont want to see
    WebBrowser1.Navigate url
    Debug.Print WebBrowser1.Document.body.InnerHTML ''' Here you can do magic if the urls you are navigating are serialisable to objects :)

End Sub
```

Now the first time you navigate to the site, you should be prompted for user name and password, on click of next, your session to saved.

Comment: Thanks sir, since we needed it immediately, we just exported it to a SharePoint List, where it is working. I will mark this as answer.