# Unable to click on close button (cross button on a tab strip) using vba

Tags: vba

[image]
[image]

```
Set objDoc = objIE.document
Set objElement = objDoc.getElementById("ext-gen2687")
```

Code execute successfully but not closed the tab strip

```
objElement.Click
```

Same using the loop code works perfectly,
holds the object of anchor elements but not closed the tab strip

```
For Each ul In objDoc.getElementsByTagName("ul")
    For Each li In ul.getElementsByTagName("li")
        For Each anchor In li.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If anchor.ID = "ext-gen2687" Then
                anchor.Click
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I am looking suspiciously at that on-click return false which prevents propagation through DOM and wondering it that is involved. Is this an internal URL or Login based?

Comment: Can you close the window by its handle?

Comment: Yes it is login based URL after login I see these tab strip.

Comment: No, I did not tried using handle. By the way I don't know how to do it by handle :(

Comment: Some backgrounf info http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=52 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705797/find-the-window-handle-for-a-chrome-browser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa   and similar type resources

Comment: Thanks for the reference and Sorry, I did not make myself clear. This is not a GUI window. It is a web page and in the web page if I click on any link then it opens as tab strip on the same web page. I have shared the Image of Tab strip and just down the HTML code of that tab strip.

Comment: My fault....I didn't pay enough attention to the display.